# compass compile error (undefined mixin "set-legacy-ie-support")

Tags: compass-sass, susy-compass

For the last 2 days I get this error while compiling my sass files.

Compass was unable to compile one or more files in the project:

```
error style.scss (Line 58 of _media.scss: Undefined mixin 'set-legacy-ie-support'.)
create style.css
```

I do have the following libraries installed

```
breakpoint-1.3      compass-0.12.2      rubygems-update-1.8.24  sassy-buttons-0.1.4
chunky_png-1.2.6    fssm-0.2.9      sass-3.2.1      susy-1.0.5
```

Can anybody tell me where this mixin supposed to be? If I do a recursive search in /Library/Ruby there ain't no mixin with that name. I can't figure it out. Please someone?

Regards Norman

Comment: It's not a mixin, but rather a configuration variable. [Here's the Compass docs for it](http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/support/). What is on line 58 of _media.scss?

Comment: Thank for your reply.. On line 58 is: @include set-legacy-ie-support;

Comment: I just found the mixin... in susy/_support.scss which is included in _susy.scss

Comment: But still got the error... I'm stuck here..

Comment: And you're requiring susy in your config.rb file?

Comment: Yes I am..
require "susy"
require "compass"
require "sassy-buttons"

Comment: Stupid me.. for some reason there was a local copy of _susy.scss in my project dir. So the compiler couldn't find the additional files. I removed it and now it's fixed. Thanks Steveax for your replies... Norman

Comment: NP, glad you figured it out. You may want to expand on the solution and post it as an answer so it'll be more helpful to others that have the same issue.

Comment: Because this is the first time I'm using Sass and Susy I did combination of a "gem install susy" and a "manual" installation. For some reason it did work for some time though. Removing the manual installed susy files en directory the problem was fixed.